# Confusion between celery and celeryd

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I have successfully installed celery and django celery in my django app. I have followed a number of tutorials in an effort to understand it. Some start the worker with celery like so:

```
python manage.py celery worker --loglevel=info
```

others start it with celery**d**:

```
python manage.py celeryd –-verbosity=2 –loglevel=DEBUG
```

I have 2 questions please:

1. Which one should I be using?
2. The celeryd command is not working (see exception below). How can i fix it?

   File "manage.py", line 10, in 
       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "/Users/juankruger/.virtualenvs/pony/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
       utility.execute()   File "/Users/juankruger/.virtualenvs/pony/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 377, in execute
       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "/Users/juankruger/.virtualenvs/pony/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/management/base.py", line 81, in run_from_argv
       self.handle_default_options(argv[2:])   File "/Users/juankruger/.virtualenvs/pony/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/management/base.py", line 91, in handle_default_options
       if '--settings=' in arg: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: is `--loglevel=info` working in celeryd ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`celeryd` is the old version of `celery worker`.You can use both.But prefer latest.Then error is in your syntax.Try this

```
python manage.py celeryd --verbosity=2 --loglevel=DEBUG
```